# Python tkinter оптимизация длины и вывод в классы

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп, классы, tkinter

В конце кода у меня есть большой блок следующего вида (ниже).

Он очень громоздкий и не красивый. Как можно сократить количество строк или возможно создать какой-то класс, позволяющий уменьшить количество строк и сделать это всё более приятным и архитектурно правильным?

Ссылка на полный код:
https://cloud.mail.ru/public/CJHy/kzUPMj5jJ

```
Entryx1 = Entry()
Entryx2 = Entry()
Entryx3 = Entry()
Entryy1 = Entry()
Entryy2 = Entry()
Entryy3 = Entry()

Entryx1.insert(0,(x1))
Entryx2.insert(0,(x2))
Entryx3.insert(0,(x3))
Entryy1.insert(0,(y1))
Entryy2.insert(0,(y2))
Entryy3.insert(0,(y3))

Entryx1.place(relx=0.1,rely=0.8)
Entryx2.place(relx=0.3,rely=0.8)
Entryx3.place(relx=0.5,rely=0.8)
Entryy1.place(relx=0.1,rely=0.9)
Entryy2.place(relx=0.3,rely=0.9)
Entryy3.place(relx=0.5,rely=0.9)

Labelx1 = Label(text='X1:', fg='red',font='Arial 14 bold')
Labelx2 = Label(text='X2:', fg='red',font='Arial 14 bold')
Labelx3 = Label(text='X3:', fg='red',font='Arial 14 bold')
Labely1 = Label(text='Y1:', fg='red',font='Arial 14 bold')
Labely2 = Label(text='Y2:', fg='red',font='Arial 14 bold')
Labely3 = Label(text='Y3:', fg='red',font='Arial 14 bold')

Labelx1.place(relx=0.1,rely=0.75)
Labelx2.place(relx=0.3,rely=0.75)
Labelx3.place(relx=0.5,rely=0.75)
Labely1.place(relx=0.1,rely=0.85)
Labely2.place(relx=0.3,rely=0.85)
Labely3.place(relx=0.5,rely=0.85)
```

Полный код:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title('Рейтинговая работа Евгений Львович')
root.geometry('800x768')

class Colorize: # Создание класса для переключателей
    def __init__(self, color, val,translate):
        Radiobutton(
            group_for_radiobutton,
            text=translate.capitalize(),
            command=lambda i=color: change_triangle_color(i),
            variable=var, value=val).pack()

def change_button(): # Функция для изменения ФИО на ID
    if my_button['text'] == my_id:
        my_button['text'] = 'Евгений Львович'
    else:
        my_button['text'] = my_id

def change_triangle_color(color): # Функция изменения цвета треугольника
    canv.itemconfig(my_polygon, fill = color)

shift_x = 50 # Сдвиг по оси X
shift_y = 400 # Сдвиг по оси Y

# Функция перерисовки треугольника от введенных значений
def redraw_triangle(event):
    try:
        x1 = str(int(Entryx1.get()) + shift_x)
        x2 = str(int(Entryx2.get()) + shift_x)
        x3 = str(int(Entryx3.get()) + shift_x)
        y1 = str(shift_y - int(Entryy1.get()))
        y2 = str(shift_y - int(Entryy2.get()))
        y3 = str(shift_y - int(Entryy3.get()))
        global my_polygon
        canv.delete(my_polygon)
        my_polygon = canv.create_polygon(([x1,y1],[x2,y2],[x3,y3]), fill="red")
    except Exception:
        pass

# Заголовок в виде кнопки без обрамления
my_button = Button(text='Евгений Львович',bd=0,font='Arial 14')
my_id = '70160611'
my_id_divided = str((int(my_id) // 3))
my_button.config(command=change_button)
my_button.place(relx=0.33,y=0)

# Выбор значений из ID
x1 = int(my_id[2:4])
x2 = int(my_id[4:6])
x3 = int(my_id[6:8])
y1 = int(my_id_divided[2:4])
y2 = int(my_id_divided[4:6])
y3 = int(my_id_divided[6:8])


group_for_radiobutton = LabelFrame() # Объединение во фрейм
group_for_radiobutton.place(relx=0.8,rely=0.1)

# Отрисовка холста и текста
canv = Canvas(root, width=500, height=500)
canv.create_text(470,415,fill="red",font="Times 15 bold",text="X")
canv.create_text(30,15,fill="red",font="Times 15 bold",text="Y")
canv.place(relx=0.1,rely=0.1)

# Создание системы координат
canv.create_line(20, 400, 500, 400, fill='red',
                 width=5, arrow=LAST,
                 activefill='lightgreen',
                 arrowshape="15 20 5")

canv.create_line(50, 430, 50, 0, fill='blue',
                 width=5, arrow=LAST,
                 activefill='lightgreen',
                 arrowshape="15 20 5")

# Отрисовка изначального треугольника
my_polygon = canv.create_polygon(([(x1 + shift_x), (shift_y - y1)],
                                  [(x2 + shift_x),(shift_y - y2)],
                                  [(x3 + shift_x),(shift_y - y3)]), fill="red")

# Создание переключателей через класс Colorize, передача аргументов
var = IntVar()
var.set(0)
Colorize('red',0,"Красный")
Colorize('orange',1,"Оранжевый")
Colorize('yellow',2,"Желтый")
Colorize('green',3,"Зеленый")
Colorize('lightblue',4,"Голубой")
Colorize('blue',5,"Синий")
Colorize('purple',6,"Фиолетовый")

# Функция привязки действий клавиатуры к функции redraw_triangle
root.bind('<Key>', redraw_triangle)

Entryx1 = Entry()
Entryx2 = Entry()
Entryx3 = Entry()
Entryy1 = Entry()
Entryy2 = Entry()
Entryy3 = Entry()

Entryx1.insert(0,(x1))
Entryx2.insert(0,(x2))
Entryx3.insert(0,(x3))
Entryy1.insert(0,(y1))
Entryy2.insert(0,(y2))
Entryy3.insert(0,(y3))

Entryx1.place(relx=0.1,rely=0.8)
Entryx2.place(relx=0.3,rely=0.8)
Entryx3.place(relx=0.5,rely=0.8)
Entryy1.place(relx=0.1,rely=0.9)
Entryy2.place(relx=0.3,rely=0.9)
Entryy3.place(relx=0.5,rely=0.9)

Labelx1 = Label(text='X1:', fg='red',font='Arial 14 bold')
Labelx2 = Label(text='X2:', fg='red',font='Arial 14 bold')
Labelx3 = Label(text='X3:', fg='red',font='Arial 14 bold')
Labely1 = Label(text='Y1:', fg='red',font='Arial 14 bold')
Labely2 = Label(text='Y2:', fg='red',font='Arial 14 bold')
Labely3 = Label(text='Y3:', fg='red',font='Arial 14 bold')

Labelx1.place(relx=0.1,rely=0.75)
Labelx2.place(relx=0.3,rely=0.75)
Labelx3.place(relx=0.5,rely=0.75)
Labely1.place(relx=0.1,rely=0.85)
Labely2.place(relx=0.3,rely=0.85)
Labely3.place(relx=0.5,rely=0.85)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve]

Comment: Добавил в пост ссылку на код

Comment: пожалуйста, добавьте пример обычным текстом в вопрос.

Comment: Добавил обычным текстом

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете использовать **setattr()** / **getattr()**
для динамического создания переменных, как показано ниже:

Атрибут класса создается с помощью **setattr**():

```
setattr(self, "Entryx{}".format(i), self.Entryx)     # пусть i=1
```

Использование так:

```
self.Entryx1.get())
```

или так:

```
for i in range(1, 4):
    obj = getattr(self, "Entryx{}".format(i))
    obj.insert(0, (xs[i-1][0]))
    obj.place(relx=xs[i-1][1],rely=xs[i-1][2])
```

---

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title('Рейтинговая работа Евгений Львович')
root.geometry('800x768')


class Colorize:                   # Создание класса для переключателей
    def __init__(self, color, val,translate):
        Radiobutton(
            group_for_radiobutton,
            text=translate.capitalize(),
            command=lambda i=color: change_triangle_color(i),
            variable=var, value=val).pack()


def change_button():              # Функция для изменения ФИО на ID
    if my_button['text'] == my_id:
        my_button['text'] = 'Евгений Львович'
    else:
        my_button['text'] = my_id


def change_triangle_color(color): # Функция изменения цвета треугольника
    canv.itemconfig(my_polygon, fill = color)


shift_x = 50                      # Сдвиг по оси X
shift_y = 400                     # Сдвиг по оси Y


# Функция перерисовки треугольника от введенных значений
def redraw_triangle(event):
    try:
#        x1 = str(int(Entryx1.get()) + shift_x)                      # ---
        x1 = str(int(x_l['x1'].get()) + shift_x)                     # + x_l['x1']  
        x2 = str(int(x_l['x2'].get()) + shift_x)                     # + x_l['x2'] 
        x3 = str(int(x_l['x3'].get()) + shift_x)                     # + x_l['x3'] 

#        y1 = str(shift_y - int(Entryy1.get()))                      # ---
        y1 = str(shift_y - int(y_l['y1'].get()))                     # + y_l['y1'] 
        y2 = str(shift_y - int(y_l['y2'].get()))                     # + y_l['y2']
        y3 = str(shift_y - int(y_l['y3'].get()))                     # + y_l['y3']

        global my_polygon
        canv.delete(my_polygon)
        my_polygon = canv.create_polygon(([x1, y1], [x2, y2], [x3, y3]), fill="red")
    except Exception:
        pass


# Заголовок в виде кнопки без обрамления
my_button = Button(text='Евгений Львович',bd=0,font='Arial 14')
my_id = '70160611'
my_id_divided = str((int(my_id) // 3))
my_button.config(command=change_button)
my_button.place(relx=0.33,y=0)

# Выбор значений из ID
x1 = int(my_id[2:4])
x2 = int(my_id[4:6])
x3 = int(my_id[6:8])
y1 = int(my_id_divided[2:4])
y2 = int(my_id_divided[4:6])
y3 = int(my_id_divided[6:8])

xs = [[x1, 0.1, 0.8]  , [x2, 0.3, 0.8], [x3, 0.5, 0.8]]              # +++
ys = [[y1, 0.1, 0.9]  , [y2, 0.3, 0.9], [y3, 0.5, 0.9]]              # +++

group_for_radiobutton = LabelFrame()    # Объединение во фрейм
group_for_radiobutton.place(relx=0.8,rely=0.1)

# Отрисовка холста и текста
canv = Canvas(root, width=500, height=500)
canv.create_text(470, 415, fill="red", font="Times 15 bold", text="X")
canv.create_text(30, 15, fill="red", font="Times 15 bold", text="Y")
canv.place(relx=0.1, rely=0.1)

# Создание системы координат
canv.create_line(
    20, 400, 500, 400, fill='red',
    width=5, arrow=LAST,
    activefill='lightgreen',
    arrowshape="15 20 5"
)

canv.create_line(
    50, 430, 50, 0, fill='blue',
    width=5, arrow=LAST,
    activefill='lightgreen',
    arrowshape="15 20 5"
)

# Отрисовка изначального треугольника
my_polygon = canv.create_polygon(
    ([(x1 + shift_x), (shift_y - y1)],
     [(x2 + shift_x),(shift_y - y2)],
     [(x3 + shift_x),(shift_y - y3)]
    ), 
    fill="red"
)

# Создание переключателей через класс Colorize, передача аргументов
var = IntVar()
var.set(0)
Colorize('red', 0, "Красный")
Colorize('orange', 1, "Оранжевый")
Colorize('yellow', 2, "Желтый")
Colorize('green', 3, "Зеленый")
Colorize('lightblue', 4, "Голубой")
Colorize('blue', 5, "Синий")
Colorize('purple', 6, "Фиолетовый")

# Функция привязки действий клавиатуры к функции redraw_triangle
root.bind('<Key>', redraw_triangle)


# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
class MyEntry: 
    def __init__(self, i, listEntryx={}, listEntryy={}, 
                          listLabelx={}, listLabely={}):
        super().__init__()
        self.listEntryx = listEntryx
        self.listEntryy = listEntryy
        #?self.listLabelx = listLabelx
        #?self.listLabely = listLabely

        self.Entryx = Entry()
        # Атрибут класса создается с помощью setattr()        
        setattr(self, "Entryx{}".format(i), self.Entryx) 
        self.getEntryx(i, f'x{i}')
        
        self.Entryy = Entry()
        setattr(self, "Entryy{}".format(i), self.Entryy)
        self.getEntryy(i, f'y{i}') 
        
        self.Labelx = Label(text=f'X{i}:', fg='red',font='Arial 14 bold')
        setattr(self, "Labelx{}".format(i), self.Labelx)
        obj = getattr(self, "Labelx{}".format(i))
        obj.place(relx=xs[i-1][1],rely=0.75) 
        #?self.listLabelx[f'lx{i}'] = obj

        self.Labely = Label(text=f'Y{i}:', fg='red',font='Arial 14 bold')
        setattr(self, "Labely{}".format(i), self.Labely)
        obj = getattr(self, "Labely{}".format(i))
        obj.place(relx=xs[i-1][1],rely=0.85) 
        #?self.listLabely[f'ly{i}'] = obj
        
    def getEntryx(self, i, k):
        obj = getattr(self, "Entryx{}".format(i))
        obj.insert(0, (xs[i-1][0]))
        obj.place(relx=xs[i-1][1],rely=xs[i-1][2])        
        self.listEntryx[k] = obj
        
    def getEntryy(self, i, k):
        obj = getattr(self, "Entryy{}".format(i))
        obj.insert(0, (ys[i-1][0]))
        obj.place(relx=ys[i-1][1],rely=ys[i-1][2])       
        self.listEntryy[k] = obj
        
    def allList(self):
        return  self.listEntryx, self.listEntryy
        
        
listEntry = []
for i in range(1, 4):
    myEntry = MyEntry(i)

x_l, y_l = myEntry.allList()
# print(*x_l.items(), sep='\n')
# print(*y_l, sep='\n')
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 

    
'''
Entryx1 = Entry()
Entryx2 = Entry()
Entryx3 = Entry()
Entryy1 = Entry()
Entryy2 = Entry()
Entryy3 = Entry()

Entryx1.insert(0,(x1))
Entryx2.insert(0,(x2))
Entryx3.insert(0,(x3))
Entryy1.insert(0,(y1))
Entryy2.insert(0,(y2))
Entryy3.insert(0,(y3))

Entryx1.place(relx=0.1,rely=0.8)
Entryx2.place(relx=0.3,rely=0.8)
Entryx3.place(relx=0.5,rely=0.8)
Entryy1.place(relx=0.1,rely=0.9)
Entryy2.place(relx=0.3,rely=0.9)
Entryy3.place(relx=0.5,rely=0.9)

Labelx1 = Label(text='X1:', fg='red',font='Arial 14 bold')
Labelx2 = Label(text='X2:', fg='red',font='Arial 14 bold')
Labelx3 = Label(text='X3:', fg='red',font='Arial 14 bold')
Labely1 = Label(text='Y1:', fg='red',font='Arial 14 bold')
Labely2 = Label(text='Y2:', fg='red',font='Arial 14 bold')
Labely3 = Label(text='Y3:', fg='red',font='Arial 14 bold')

Labelx1.place(relx=0.1,rely=0.75)
Labelx2.place(relx=0.3,rely=0.75)
Labelx3.place(relx=0.5,rely=0.75)
Labely1.place(relx=0.1,rely=0.85)
Labely2.place(relx=0.3,rely=0.85)
Labely3.place(relx=0.5,rely=0.85)
'''

root.mainloop()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]